# Decimal numbers: comma vs point

Tags: windows

My Windows writes the decimal numbers with a comma e.g. "3,14159"; But an 
application requires to use decimal point e.g. "3.14159".

Is it possible to change this configuration in DOS console?

Thank you!

Comment: It's a region setting in Windows, I don't have a laptop with my to look for it, but to get the best help you should really tell us your windows version and country.

Comment: Hi! I want to make a cmd file where: change the decimal notation, run the application and return de original decimal notation.